# Minecraft Mod not adding content

Tags: intellij-idea, minecraft

I'm currently trying to learn how to make Minecraft mods in Intellij and I'm fresh off a set of tutorials on youtube but when I try to run Minecraft with the content I've added there just isn't anything there. The only evidence my mod has even loaded is the name of it in the Mods section. It is as if I just ran regular Minecraft. I can't help but notice that my Java classes are orange when my Java classes in the tutorial files are white. I copied over the Java classes from the tutorial mod I needed to my first mod.

[image: Directories]

I've looked through the internet but can't find anything that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe using this plugin will give some help: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8327-minecraft-development
https://mcdev.io/docs/